# Want to update mutiple records with update trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update

Let me explain my scenario. 
Let say I have 10 records in my "Activities" Table with "EstimatedDate" column. Each record is unique and have a different "EstimatedDate". These all 10 records belongs to one project, with same "ProjectId".
If I change the "EstimatedDate" of one row it should automatically change the below rows in the table which has the same "ProjectId".

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Activities_Update
ON dbo.Activities
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  UPDATE a
    SET EstimatedDate = i.EstimatedDate
    FROM dbo.Activities AS a
    INNER JOIN inserted AS i
    ON a.ProjectId = i.ProjectId
    WHERE a.EstimatedDate <> i.EstimatedDate;
END
GO
```

While it's unlikely that your `UPDATE` statement looks like this:

```
UPDATE Activities SET EstimatedDate = CASE
  WHEN ActivityID = 1 THEN GETDATE()
  WHEN ActivityID = 2 THEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE()) END
WHERE ProjectID = 1;
```

If you want to use the `MAX` date from `inserted`, you could say:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Activities_Update
ON dbo.Activities
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  ;WITH i AS (SELECT ProjectId, d = MAX(EstimatedDate)
    FROM inserted GROUP BY ProjectId)
  UPDATE a
    SET EstimatedDate = i.d
    FROM dbo.Activities AS a
    INNER JOIN i
    ON a.ProjectId = i.ProjectId
    WHERE a.EstimatedDate <> i.d;
END
GO
```

Latter is untested.

Comment: What would the behaviour be if multiple records, for the same ProjectID, get updated to different new EstimatedDates?  Would it be worth *(I guess this is a question to the OP)* specifying a behaviour?  *(Such as choosing the MAX() of the new EstimatedDate values?)*

Comment: @Dems that's a good point. While the trigger does handle multiple rows, I had only considered the actual implementation for a single row being affected. Updated.